# Save UIButton state

Tags: ios, imagebutton, swift3

class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var instructions: UIButton!

@IBAction func instructions(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    instructions.isHidden = true


}
```

This is my code to display instructions on how to use the app. 
I currently have an image-button and when I click on it the image disappears. This works great but I don't want the instructions to pop up overtime someone opens the app. I want to use "Userdefaults" to save the state of the button.
I just recently updated to swift 3.0 and I can't find anyone who explains how to it, please help!

Comment: you mean control state?

Comment: or you want to save button hidden state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UserDefaults.standard().set("True", forKey: "isHidden")

print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isHidden")!)")
```

Answer (score 1):

UserDefaults is very helpful dictionary for storing some user defined preferences. It is already available from iOS version 2.0.

It is able to save `Int`, `Bool`, `String`, `Array`, `Dictionary`, `Date` and more.

Swift 3:

**Setting:**

```
// put this code right into the @IBAction methods of your UIButton event
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(true, forKey: "InstructionsButtonIsHidden")
```

**Retrievals:**

```
// you may need to put these lines in your didFinishLaunching or viewDidLoad method 
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let isHidden = defaults.bool(forKey: "InstructionsButtonIsHidden")
```

Be aware not to save too much data as it could slow your app's launch.